# Regexp invalid interval and unescaped chars

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this regexp:

> /(.*wwa)?#{var}([1-2]?)/

And I am getting two warnings:
Regexp has invalid interval
regexp has '}' without escape

I am sure it's something obvious i am missing but I can't find what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce this is to go back to Ruby 1.8.7 and have `var` contain `#{}`, optionally with something between the brackets.

First, if you upgrade your Ruby, you shouldn't get those errors anymore.

Second, I suspect you have a bug if `var` does have an interpolation string in it.